# Adding Dollar Sign($) in a VScode Code snippet

Tags: json, vscode-snippets

I was writing my custom **code snippets** for verilog files in **VScode**; VSCode uses *JSON* files for it.
I observed that **$** before finish and dumpvars statements doesn't get printed when I use the snippet since it is a built-in keyword for including variables in strings in json file format,
I have tried adding \ before $ but that **didn't** work. 
**Is there any way I can insert $ in my snippets?**

This is the relevant code block I am using:

```
"dump statements": {
        "prefix": "dump",
        "body": [
            "initial begin", 
            "   dumpfile(\"${1:filename}\");",
            "   \$dumpvars();",
            "end"
        ],
        "description": "Prints the dump file and variables statements."
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double backslash to escape it, like this `\\$`

```
"dump statements": {
    "prefix": "dump",
    "body": [
        "initial begin", 
        "   dumpfile(\"${1:filename}\");",
        "   \\$dumpvars();",
        "end"
    ],
    "description": "Prints the dump file and variables statements."
},
```